# is there any way to access a union type property as an array of values to perform a dynamic type check?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

currently I'm writing code similar to this:

```
interface A {
  type: 'A'
}

interface B {
  type: 'B'
}

interface C {
  type: 'C'
}

type AorBorC = A | B | C

type AorB = A | B

const returnOnlyAorBs = (x: AorBorC): AorB => {
  if (x.type === 'A' || x.type === 'B') {
    return x;
  }

  throw new Error('unexpected type');
}
```

which typechecks perfectly,

only problem is my real 'AorBorC' type is a much larger union.

I'd really much like to be able to write something like:

```
const IdealReturnOnlyAorBs = (x: AorBorC): AorB => {
  if (AorB['type'].includes(x.type)) {
    return x;
  }

  throw new Error('unexpected type');
}
```

Seems to me that it could be possible as the type checker perfecly knows what `AorB['type']` is because I can use it as a type... I know how to define types based on const arrays, basically I'm asking if the reverse is possible.

If not, are there any useful patterns that could simplify my use case? I.e. narrowing a large union type to a smaller union type safely.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) could be close in theory, since it can be any predicate function. It isn't the exact request but it may help to accomplish the desire.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLATwAcIAuZAclXKwF8stRJZEUAhTHPI0i16uhuGjwkyAMIdcBYmXJj+9aSlQB7KKzUSAvGmQAfZOwNjF3NGvY70B1vQQqQAZzDJgj1euQ6AFAA8yHhpQYgCUZL6ujuaeWgB8krjIUBBgAK5QIMi+AHRKXlo6AESohfoGOXkFRayFtHYOzkkp6SAA8iAANviBUT7+0UGhARZe8di4wDDI3m6BfiEhCbjJaRlZANycAlIAFlAqAO7IIBBHAKJQ+1De5KknvsQIkAAmXMTkIZs0QA

```
const isAorB = (x: AorBorC): x is AorB => {
    return ["A", "B"].includes(x.type)
}

const returnOnlyAorBs = (x: AorBorC): AorB => {
  if (isAorB(x)) {
    return x;
  }

  throw new Error('unexpected type');
}
```

Another way that is similar could be using enums since they are one of the Typescript artifacts that live on at runtime. Using an enum in this fashion is not ideal and a bit brittle.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygbwFBSgQQDRZQBCB2AwhgL4YYCWIALsAE4BmAhgMbC7qEOJgALliDkAOhxUa9Jmy48ifbAKQj4SCUWl1GLDtyhllUVcNGbxFahjO4A9syKPjAXl4AfYlC8VbghycodxwfYhpOexBkBihaZBxHJXcACgAPEUSnFwBKETS41CzkgD4TbGZgBjBmECg08TsAHgsUKx1I6NjK6tqAeRAAGzhi1FSMwOdmMjzJ4LLMbFpWKBT44vScnPKoHpq6tIBuQhsVAAtmewB3KBBgG4BRZkvmFIByMDu0pE4mABNTII3jljpQgA

```
enum Types {
  A,
  B,
  C
}

const isAorB = (x: AorBorC): x is AorB => {
    return x.type < Types.C
}
```